# Node - Express -App does not respond to other servers

Tags: node.js, express, curl

On Virtual Machine 1 I have a very simple node script

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var annotations = require('./routes/annotations');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.options('/annotations/:id', cors());
app.get('/annotations/:id', annotations.findById);

app.listen(80, function()  {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

When I access with the browser or curl from my local machine http://example.com/annotations/5770dffb2dc30a7433c729f7 I get instantly the correct data.

But when I try to it from Virtual Machine 2 with a PHP script (file_get_contents or curl), with CURL or even with w3m I cannot access it. PHP and CURL are trying it for long time and then run finally into timeouts, w3m says

```
Can't load http://example.com/annotations/5770dffb2dc30a7433c729f7.
```

I am loosing my mind! Any suggestions?

Comment: No, unfortunately that was not the error and the typo was only in the example. Would have been to easy...

Comment: Does VM1 have a firewall?

Comment: Yes, but I can not modify the settings. Wrote the tech support to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the issue is the network, not node. Please check if you can

```
ping 10.55.55.111
```

from your 2nd VM, assuming that your first VM's IP address running node is 10.55.55.111. If that fails, you have a network problem.

Two possible solutions:

- Your two VMs are on different subnets. A great article about VM network adapters can be found at https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html.
- Maybe your first virtual machine has a "Host-only" network? You might need to set the virtual adapter to "Bridged" instead. Further explanation of "Host-only" and "Bridged" network adapters is given at http://slopjong.de/2013/05/14/virtualbox-make-your-virtual-machine-accessible-from-your-host-system-but-not-from-the-local-network/.

Comment: I could not even ping. Should have done this at first, and check if there is a connection at at all from one VM to the other before. I was so obesssed with CORS settings and so on, that I overlooked the basics. As I am not allowed to edit my virtual machine configuration by myself, I contacted our tech support now and sent them your guesses.

Comment: Okay, let me know if any of them solved the problem!

Comment: Yes it did. Different Subnets as far as I understood.